# Series vs parallel solenoids

Tags: electromagnetism, inductance

Something I'm sort of struggling to figure out.  Let's say I have a given length of wire to make solenoids.  I wrap it tightly in all cases and get some turns per distance $n$ that will remain constant, as will the current through my coils, $i$, and the area of my coils, $A$.  In one case I wrap all my turns serially, like a normal solenoid.  In the other, I segment my turns into multiple parallel solenoids.  Intuitively, I'd expect that both should produce the same overall magnetic flux.  But since magnetic flux of a solenoid is
$$
\Phi=\mu n i A
$$
it almost seems like my extra coils on my long solenoid are wasted.  That is, I add more coils but get no more increase in magnetic flux since my coils per distance is constant.  In fact, it doesn't seem like I really get anything extra by adding more coils.  But when I take those extra coils and put them into separate solenoids, since they have the same turns per length (just differing by number of turns, but that isn't in the equation) as the long solenoid they have the same flux and superposition says if I add their individual fluxes, my total magnetic flux increases by the number of parallel solenoids I add.

So, why are these different?  Why shouldn't my single solenoid be the same as my multiple small ones?  If this is true, shouldn't physical solenoids be made just by wrapping a few turns rather than many since that's equivalent?  The only thing I can think of is that I'm using the wrong equation.  That is, that equation is the equation for an infinite solenoid and I should be using the one for a finite one.  But it seems like even if I have say one very long solenoid and two smaller (but still suitably long) solenoids, I still have the same problem.

Comment: Are you forgetting about the $n$ in your equation? Isn't that the number of turns?

Comment: I really don't see how it makes sense to add coils to an infinite solenoid.  The formula for a finite solenoid includes N as the number of turns total rather than the number of turns per length, so that is the formula you should be using.

Comment: @solomonSlow You're confusing $n$ and $N$.  $n$ is turns per length, sometimes expressed as $N/L$, making the equation $\Phi=\frac{\mu N iA}{L}$  $N$ is number of turns.

Comment: @BillWatts So, I went and tried this with the equation for a finite solenoid.  Assuming you take flux density at the end of the solenoid, the equation becomes, $B_z=\frac{\mu N I}{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2+l^2}}$.  If $l >> R$, then this reduces to the same as for an infinite solenoid ($B=\mu n I$).  Since the terms are squared, a solenoid doesn't have to be hugely longer than its radius for the approximation to be valid.

Comment: But my point was when you use the infinite solenoid formula, you are assuming the solenoid is infinite.  If you add coils to an infinite solenoid, you still have the same infinite solenoid and naturally the flux will not change.   If you are at the end of a finite solenoid, add coils to the other side of you, where now you are in the middle and see how that changes the flux.  Why are you using $l >>R$ anyway?